# firefox can't establish connection with localhost while running a cherrypy tutorial example in Fedora core

Tags: python

my configuration

```
[global]
server.socket_host = "0.0.0.0"
server.socket_port = 8080
server.thread_pool = 10
server.environment = "production"
server.showTracebacks = "True"
server.logToScreen = "False"
```

I have no access to "root"

Please suggest me anythin

Comment: Do you have any firewall active?

Comment: Which version of cherrypy are you running? It seems there is a bug in version < 3.0. Can you check?

Answer (score 1):

Make your socket host address as "localhost" or correct ip address.

```
[global]
server.socket_host = ""
server.socket_port = 8080
```

[Edit:]

There seems to be a bug in cherrypy < 3.0

server.socket_host

> This setting binds CherryPy to a particular ip address. This isn't usually necessary, as CherryPy will listen for any incoming connections by default. The exception is when your application is running on a system which has both a IPv4 and IPv6 network stack. By default the CherryPy server will only listen on the IPv6 interfaces. Normally, to listen on all IPv4 interfaces, you would set server.socket_host = '0.0.0.0' but unfortunately, due to a bug in CherryPy <= 3.0, this causes an error on some systems. The workaround is to set server.socket_host to a specific interface address and run your application behind a reverse proxy that listens on all interfaces and forwards requests to your application.